# Correct data type in access for a insert long integer into database

Tags: c#, ms-access-2007

When I run this query it doesn't work because microsoft access doesn't insert this long integer.

```
INSERT INTO test(id,`date`,v,s,vi)VALUES(@channelId,NOW(),2276981717,14835183,239)
```

I am using Jet engine in C# to connect Access databe file. Small integer get inserted but not this one. The v,s, vi is currently long integer. I want to know which is the correct data type to store this kind of long integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it `Double`, I tested it on my machine MS Access 2013 and its working fine with your values.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at this table ...

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_datatypes.asp

It would seem you need to use `Double`. `Long` (maximum value `2,147,483,647`) would not fit the first value (`2276981717`) and `Single` is the same size in bytes as `Long` so it won't fit in there either!

Answer (score 1):

I have tried it with long integer but it doesn't work. So as you can see from the picture, setting the datatype to double will resolve the error

Comment: The image is not posted because of my reputation status but making the data type double will work for sure.